# Will a flash of light in the dark blind people?

Tags: dnd-5e, vision-and-light

My friends and I were playing a game of D&D 5e, and we were in a dungeon with no light. All of us had darkvision. When we came across a group of dwarfs, the cleric cast Guiding Bolt on one of the enemies. The wording on the spell states that it creates a flash of light and it got the group thinking: if it is fully dark and a bright light appears, would it be like a flashbang and temporarily blind everyone? When we were looking for the ruling on this, and no one could come up with an answer. Is there a ruling on this or is it completely up to the DM?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Although there are rules for lighting (that you already know) there are no general rules what happens if the lighting suddenly changes. In reality, this is worse than the actual condition because we cannot adapt that quickly. But D&D is no simulation, so there is no rule for this.

As always, if you want to have a rule for this, talk to your DM and work one out for your group.

Comment: Yep, the DM will have to make a call on this. I'd assume that you could simulate the temporary blindness / disorientation via handing out disadvantages for that round's attacks.

Comment: I actually had this last night - though with an orb that floats and creates light as bright as the sun (can't remember the name offhand). The character with it is human, the rest of the party have darkvision and expected him to use it - so I called that the enemy had temporary blindness due to the unexpected light, but the party were expecting it and didn't get any penalties